# Prove that $a+b+c+d \geq \frac{2}{a+1}+\frac{2}{b+1}+\frac{2}{c+1}+\frac{2} {d+1}$

Tags: inequality

**the question**

Let $a,b,c,d>0$ with $a+b+c+d \geq \frac{1}{a}+ \frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+ \frac{1}{d}$. Prove that $a+b+c+d \geq \frac{2}{a+1}+\frac{2}{b+1}+\frac{2}{c+1}+\frac{2} {d+1}$

**the idea**

Maybe $\frac{1}{a}+a \geq 2$ would be useful...

The inequality look like could be obtained from the inequality of means, more explicit from arithmetic mean and harmonic mean :

$1+\frac{a+b+c+d}{4} \geq \frac{4}{\frac{1}{a+1}+\frac{1}{b+1}+\frac{1}{c+1}+\frac{1} {d+1}}$

I tried processing it and use $a+b+c+d \geq \frac{1}{a}+ \frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+ \frac{1}{d}$, but honestly I got to nothing useful.

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the inequality between harmonic and arithmetic mean:
$$
 \frac{2}{x+1} \le \frac 12 \left( \frac 1x + 1\right) \, .
$$
Now use $\frac{1}{x}+x \geq 2$ to conclude that
$$
\frac{2}{x+1} \le 
\frac 12 \left( \frac 1x + \frac 12 \left( \frac 1x + x\right) \right)
= \frac 34 \frac 1x + \frac 14 x \, .
$$
Then add these inequalities for $x = a, b, c, d$ and use the given $a+b+c+d \geq \frac{1}{a}+ \frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+ \frac{1}{d}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea! May i ask how did you conclude that $\frac{2}{x+1} \le \frac 34 \frac 1x + \frac 14 x \$?

Comment: @IONELABUCIU: $ 1 \le \frac 12 (1/x + x)$ ...